# Salesforce B2C Commerce Analytics Data Download

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-developer

In Salesforce B2C Commerce Cloud platform there is a section called Reports and Dashboard where Salesforce show metrics related to the website traffic, user interactions (searches) and other stats related to the user interactions.
I'm trying to export this data but apparently, Salesforce does not make it available through any of their API.
We can download the data manually (with some limitations) but we need to automated the data extraction.

Any suggestions? Please note that to login we use a 2FA.